# How to use if condition in structure in c

Tags: c, conditional-statements, structure

I want to store name id in a structure. then I want to print them. Condition is if there is no store data in structure print "No data". But I can't do this in if condition.

```
#include<stdio.h>


struct store
{
    char name[100];
    int id[50];
} info[100];
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter your name\n");
    scanf("%s",info[i].name);
    printf("Enter your ID\n");
    scanf("%d",info[i].id);

    if(info.name[i]!='\0')
    {
        printf("%s",info[i].name);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No data found");
    }
}
```

Comment: You never set `i`.

Comment: What value do you expect `i` to have?

Comment: If `scanf` does not write any data to `info->name`, that data is also uninitialized.  Rather than checking the content of `info->name`, you should check the value returned by scanf.  eg `if( scanf("%99s", p->name) != 1 ) { ...}`

Comment: i didn't get it. can you please elaborate

Comment: This is wrong `info.name[i]`it should be `info[i].name`.

Comment: Also, please pick a language. If this `C` or `C++`?

Comment: BTW, `info[x].name` is an array, not a single character.  Use `strcmp` for C-Style strings.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should be using `std::string` for text instead of character arrays.  The `std::string` is easier to pass, automatically manages memory and has a `size` function.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, the `scanf` function is dangerous.  There is nothing preventing `scanf` from overflowing your character array.  Use `std::string` and `getline`, or at least, use `getline`.  The `getline` function allows you to limit the quantity of characters read.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Arrays can overflow (and thus cause undefined behavior).  Using less than the capacity is a waste of memory.  If you want to change the size of the array, you'll have to manually do it (by using dynamic memory allocation).  The `std::vector` can change size at run-time and is a lot easier to pass to functions.  It also has a `size` member function.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to an array by its name only, it *decays* into a **pointer** to its 1st element.  So `info.name` will not compile, it would need to be `info->name` instead.  However, everywhere *other than* your `if` statement, you are using `info[i].name` to access the `name` of a specific element at index `i`, which is fine, but then you use `info.name[i]` in the `if` statement, which is not fine.  See the difference?  To access the 1st `char` of a `name` of a specific element, you would need `info[i].name[0]` instead.

Also, you are declaring the `id` field as an *array* of `int`s, but you really only need 1 `int`.

Also, you are not initializing the `info` array before filling it with data.

Try something more like this instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct store
{
    char name[100];
    int id;
} info[100];

int main()
{
    memset(info, 0, sizeof(info));

    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter your name\n");
    scanf("%99s", info[i].name);
    printf("Enter your ID\n");
    scanf("%d", &(info[i].id));

    if (info[i].name[0] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%d %s", info[i].id, info[i].name);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No data found");
    }
}
```